# Lucas number and exponential function

Tags: combinatorics, lucas-numbers

This is referring to Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics book, Chapter 1 Ex6.

For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ define $J_{n}(2x)=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{(-1)^kx^{n+2k}}{k!(n+k)!}$ Let $\frac{1}{j!}=0$ if $j<0$. Show that $e^x = \sum_{n≥0} L_nJ_n(2x)$ where $L_n$ is the Lucas number.

Edit: I've tried to show that RHS satisfies the property that $\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n≥0} L_nJ_n(2x) = \sum_{n≥0} L_nJ_n(2x)$ but it gets messy. I've also tried to use $f(a+b) = f(a)f(b)$ on RHS but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.